# default value for switch in access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am using switch statement in access 2007, i want to know how I can specify default value

```
select 
  switch
  (
  MyCol = 1, 'Value is One',
  MyCol = 2, 'Value is Two'
  ) from MyTable
```

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
SELECT
Switch(MyTable.[MyCol]='1','Terrestrial',
MyTable.[MyCol]='2','Value is two',MyTable.[MyCol]='3','Value is three',
True,'Error') AS ColumnName
FROM MyTable;
```

Comment: i am asking for ms-access querry

Answer (score 14):

```
select 
  switch
  (
  MyCol = 1, 'Value is One',
  MyCol = 2, 'Value is Two'
  True,"Default"
  ) from MyT
```

**Refer:**

http://www.utteraccess.com/forum/Switch-statement-default-t453140.html

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the Swich command is:

`Switch(TestCase1, Result1, TestCase2, Result2, {As many more TestCases and Results as you need...}, DefaultResult)`

Note that the **DefaultResult** is an optional parameter and will provide a response in the event that the actual data does not match any of the Test Cases.